# How to do grouping in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have data from a query like 
[image]

Need to create a report in ssrs like
[image]

I am able to achieve but cannot make the supplements come right. I am only able to get the 1 st supplement.

[image]

Comment: You will not be able to achieve this, as ssrs works on per row basis. What you could achieve is grouping under organizationname i.e type Abc and then under it supplement 1 and supplement 2

Comment: I'd recommend shaping the data better in whatever source you're pulling from.  So creating a procedure/view that puts the data into the shape you need to consume it in.